# I'm working in spring batch. I need to connect to azure blob storage and get all files from there in. In Item Reader of batch how to do this?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, azure-blob-storage

In item reader I have to make connection to blob storage ang get all files in container and pass it to Item processor of spring batch. I'm new to spring batch so please help me out.

Project Structure:
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUoYL.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try with using Spring Boot Starter `azure-spring-boot-starter-storage` to auto-configure Azure Blob storage in Spring projects. This library allows you to interact with Azure Blob storage using Spring

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-storage)

There is method called  [ListBlobs()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobs?view=azure-java-legacy)
Returns an enumerable collection of blob items for the container. After getting all files read them in loop pass It to Item processor of spring batch.

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java?tabs=powershell#list-the-blobs-in-a-container)